# pyside QPushButton setCheckable

Tags: python, pyside

I would like to create a QPushButton that stays pressed until the user presses it again. I know I can use setCheckable for this. But I am unsure how to create a proper signal for the button that is triggered when the button changes state, pressed and unpressed. Toggled seems to work, but it is sending 3 arguments. I am unsure what the 3 args being sent are in my example.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
import shiboken2

class widget():
    def __init__(self):
        self.objs = ["box_1","box_2","box_3"]

    def label_event(self,text):
        print("this is the pressed button's label", text)

    def populate(self):
        for obj in self.objs:
            label = QtWidgets.QPushButton(obj)
            label.setCheckable(True)
            label.toggled.connect(partial(self.label_event, obj))
            self.vertical_layout_main.addWidget(label)

    def palette_ui(self):
        windowName = "palette"
        if cmds.window(windowName,exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(windowName, wnd = True)
        pointer = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
        parent = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(pointer),QtWidgets.QWidget)
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent)
        self.window.setObjectName(windowName)
        self.window.setWindowTitle(windowName)
        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.vertical_layout_main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.populate()        
        self.window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.window.show()        

lg = widget()
lg.palette_ui()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate the property with [`setCheckable(True)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) and use the [`toggled`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) signal:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

def function(checked):
    print("is checked?: ", checked)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    button = QtGui.QPushButton("press me")
    button.setCheckable(True)

    button.toggled.connect(function)

    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Update:

Do not use object is a reserved word, on the other hand the signal passes the parameter checked, if you want to pass another parameter you must also place it in the function:

```
def label_event(self, text, checked): # <---
    print("this is the pressed button's label", text, checked)

def populate(self):
    for obj in self.objects:
        label = QtWidgets.QPushButton(obj)
        label.setCheckable(True)
        label.toggled.connect(partial(self.label_event, obj))
        self.vertical_layout_main.addWidget(label)
```

Comment: I notice when I try to use the toggled signal with a partial function, passing an extra variable, I get an error that the slotted method is throwing an error: getting TypeError: light_label_event() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given). What are the 3 arguments being passed? button.connect(partial(event,variable)). Thank you.

Comment: @winteralfs please, edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @winteralfs your are using class?

Comment: Yes. I am.  I made some example code, but I am trying to figure out how to post it as a comment. It is too large to post as a comment.

Comment: @winteralfs edit your question, do not add it in the comments.

Comment: @winteralfs If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.